# How can I set a widget's panel to open on the left side of the screen for applications made in Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS?

Tags: web-applications, widget, arcgis

I'm using Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS to create custom web applications. I'm using a theme that allows me to place the icon for a widget in a certain slot on the left or right side of the application, but regardless of where the icon for a widget is located, in-panel widgets are all opening on the right side my application.

Can someone help me to anchor certain widget panels to the left side of the screen? I can make direct source code configuration changes if necessary, but I'm not sure what change to make for this desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Which Web AppBuilder theme are you using? Assuming the *Foldable* theme, you can add a CSS rule like this:

```
.jimu-panel.jimu-foldable-dijit.jimu-foldable-panel {
    inset: 5px auto 5px 5px !important;
}
```

[image: web appbuilder with widget open]

That will make the hovering widget move to the left. Is this what you were aiming for?